# Errno::ENOENT in Devise::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using rails 5 to create a Facebook clone as a project and I periodically get an 'Errno::ENOENT in Devise::Sessions#new' error sometimes when I start the local server. I haven't yet experienced the problem on my production server. The problem goes away once I refresh the page.

The extracted source code is below. The line that starts stylesheet_link_tag is highlighted.

```
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_rename - path/facebook/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/Ej/EjoE1YdPTMb8n3_nucZiHWaR9FpoOSZttfl56_miOS0.cache.47161664401480.4109.232718, path/facebook/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/Ej/EjoE1YdPTMb8n3_nucZiHWaR9FpoOSZttfl56_miOS0.cache)

Comment: You should post the error call stack. Where in `Device::Sessions`, what line, and how did Rails get there?

Comment: First off you can cross Devise off the list - its a Sprockets problem and has nothing to do with Devise. For some reason sprocket (which compiles CSS and JS) is failing to write (or read) cache files - it could be a privileges issue or if its highly erratic could even be a hardware issue.